# Swift Add transparent color to UIImageView background

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiimageview

```
var controllerScreen   = UIImageView()
controllerScreen.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

This adds red opaque color to the UIImageView. I want to add a transparent red color. Is there any transparent property or something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the alpha value of the red color. You can use something like this: `UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.5)`

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to @AdamPro13's answer you could do:

```
controllerScreen.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks. AdamPro'13's answer worked. So did yours. Appreciate the help!